# bad request 400 error while sending request to RestControler Spring MVC

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, rest

I am getting `bad request 400` error while sending request with `parameters to controler` I have checked whole sysntax but I did not wind any mistake, please look at my code whats wrong there?

```
var url = contextPath+"/billingControler/getOrdersByResWiseTables";
$.ajax({    
    url      : url,
    data     : "&resID="+$("#rsId").text()+"&tblid="+tableId,  
    type     : "get",     
    dataType : "json" ,
    contentType : 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    success  : function(response) {             
        console.log(response); 
    } 
});
```

error :

```
jquery-3.3.1.min.js?_=1520931033076:2 GET http://localhost:8088/smartpos/billingControler/getOrdersByResWiseTables?&resID=11&tblid=3 400 (Bad Request)
```

please check my java code

```
@RequestMapping(value="/getOrdersByResWiseTables", method=RequestMethod.GET,   produces="application/json")

public List<OrderBans> getOrdersByResWiseTables(@RequestParam("resId") String resId,@RequestParam("tblid") String tableid) {   
    String result="";
    logger.debug("Started adding order");

    RestypeIDao pdo = new RestypeIDaoImp();  

    List<OrderBans> orderList = pdo.getOrdersResWIseTbles(resId, tableid);

    System.out.println(orderList);  
    logger.debug("end adding order");
    return orderList;

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have extra `&` in your URL.

Also, you're using `data` attribute wrong, it should be an object.
Try this:

```
var url = contextPath+"/billingControler/getOrdersByResWiseTables";
$.ajax({
    url : url,
    data: {
        "resID": $("#rsId").text(),
        "tblid": tableId
    },
    dataType:"json",
    contentType:'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    success:function(response) {
        console.log(response);
    }
});
```

Comment: @bharath then there's a big chance, that you server awaits different parameters. Are you sure that the request method should be `GET` and the `contentType` is correct and that server is waiting for `resID` (and that no more parameters are required) and `tblid` parameters, and that their data type is correct?

Comment: @bharath your server awaits `resId` and you send `resID`. Notice the lower and upper case `D`